# Perform Kriging Interpolation using Arcpy

Tags: arcgis, arcpy, kriging

I have list of point feature class. I am trying to write a python script to perform Krigging interpolation. I am getting error massage in this code "Point_Num" is not defined,

Below script i am working

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

In_Point = r"D:\NPP_Test\MERRA_TEMP_2012C" #(Point feature name:r001_mean, r002_mean.....r012_mean )
Out_Raster = r"D:\NPP_Test\MERRA_TEMP_2012D"

points = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()


zFields = "GRID_CODE"

#Kriging Veriable
cellSize = 0.05
lagSize = 0.5780481172534
majorRange = 6
partialSill = 3.304292110
nugget = 0.002701348
kRadius = RadiusFixed(20000, 1)

#Mask region of interest
mask = r"D:\Gujarta Shape file\GUJARATSTATE.shp"

for zField in zFields:
    Point = Point_Num[:3]
    kModelUniversalObj = KrigingModelUniversal("LINEARDRIFT", lagSize, majorRange, partialSill, nugget)

    OutKriging = Kriging(inPointFeatures, zField, kModelUniversalObj, cellSize, kRadius)


    #IDWMASk = ExtractByMask(outIDW, mask)
    KrigMask = ExtractByMask(OutKriging, mask)
    #Save outraster as the same name of input
    KrigMask.save("r{}.tif".format(Point_Num))
```

Comment: The error message says what it says. The `PointNum` variable is not defined before you call it

Comment: Thank you. Actually i am not getting how to  iterate kriging function on all point feature and save the output as name of input .